# MSI MEG X570 unify based, brand new system - Error Code 54 in POST

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, post

First, about the system:

Corsair HX750 80+ Platinum

MSI MEG x570 unify

Ryzen 9 5900x

2 x 16GB DDR4 3600 CL19 (Corsair LP)

Powercolor RED DRAGON Radeon 6800

Samsung 980 PRO M.2 SSD 1TB

I also attached two pictures of the build after "completion" to the current point.

View: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z6g8.jpg

View: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGNzk.jpg

Turning on the power worked fine, the debug LED went through several codes each time within a few seconds, then stopped at the code 54.
According to this list:
...
...
forum-en.msi.com forum-en.msi.com

54 means an "Unspecified memory initialization error".
I must add here that the code 54 isnt even documented in the official manual for this board, which I find pretty disappointing btw....
However, I guess the above linked also applies to my board. Theres still a chance it doesnt though.

I only had two DDR4 RAM Sticks to play around with. Using them each on its own, I still got the code 54 each time.
I checked the manual, installed them correctly, DIMM A2 and B2 or only A2 when testing with single sticks.
So wrong installation shouldnt have been a problem.
I also made use of the Clear CMOS button when reconfiguring the RAM installation, so I could be clear that I didnt carry over any errors from previous tests.

I already ordered two packages with 2 RAM sticks each on amazon.
However, there is of course still a chance that its NOT the RAM sticks.

Thats why Im coming here.
First, how probable do you think it is that I got 2 faulty RAM sticks?
Second, how probable do you think its something else but the RAM?
CPU, MOBO?
I hope its neither of those, but if its one of them, I guess the MOBO is more likely?
Because if the CPU was faulty, I guess I wouldve gotten code 00?

In another forum where they talked about memory errors someone mentioned "reseating" the CPU. I dont know, what do you think?
I definitely put it in the direction ^^
Find it hard to imagine that the CPU does sit well.

Comment: I would just reseat the CPU before you purchase additional memory.  CPU issues are typically the reason a system does not POST at this stage.  That advice does not apply once the system POSTs for the first obviously.

Comment: Are you sure that the RAM is compatible with your motherboard?

Comment: @harrymc its in the official manual, so I guess it is compatible. Do you find something else?